# How to prove this trigonometric equality.

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

We have to prove that:-

$(1+\sin x)^{1/2}$ = $\left|\sin \frac{x}{2}+\cos \frac{x}{2}\right|$

I tried to multiply both numerator and denominator by $(1-\sin x)^{1/2}$
but didn't get the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sqrt{(1+\sin x)}=\sqrt{(\sin^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos^2\frac{x}{2}+2\sin\frac{x}{2}\cos\frac{x}{2})}=\sqrt{{(\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2})^2}}=|\sin\frac{x}{2}+\cos\frac{x}{2}|$

Answer (score 4):

Alternative approach:

Since both sides are non-negative, you can square both sides.

Note: $\sin(2\theta) = 2\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta).$

$[\sin(x/2) + \cos(x/2)]^2 = 1 + 2\sin(x/2)\cos(x/2) = 1 + \sin(x).$